# How can I attach the ear to my model?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I'm fairly new to blender and have been trying to make a some what cartoon looking character. I've gotten on quite well however, when it came to the ear I can't seem to get it to attach and then look clean when the subdivided surface modifier is added. If someone could take a look and see where I'm going wrong here that would be fantastic.

Thanks guys.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B88dKYvqd3wOOE54aWY1YXNNUmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you have to create on the head something like you did on nose and mouth zone (although some part of non-optimal topology is visible there...), depending on the (rear) topology of the ear. in that way you can then "cleanly" attach the ear. I'm sure that soon someone will guide you on how to do this, I can't just now...

Comment: Ear should have roughly the same level of subdivisions as the head has, otherwise Subsurf won't work correctly because there will be Ngons. The head topology isn't good as well, although depending on the task it might work. The easiest thing now is to remodel ear or find another one to roughly match amount of egde loops between the ear and head.

Comment: @G.Hamton welcome to the site, please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload blend files instead of google drive. If the link to your drive is gone then the question will no longer be as useful to others.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting and everything mentioned has been noted thanks again.